# New Portable Recorders for 2012: Olympus LS-100 and Tascam DR-100 Mk2; anyone had a go?!

Tags: new, portable-recorder, tascam, field-recording

Hi All,

I know the questions asked about portable recorders on here are numerous and repetitive but this is a very simple "question" about two devices that will be new to the market this year, within the next month or so.

I'm awaiting the (UK) launch of both the Tascam DR-100 Mk2 and the Olympus LS-100. Both look very good and I'm looking forward to heading down to my nearest store to see both in-the-plastic'n'metal.

I'm keen to hear views on both recorders, especially the Olympus, which, besides looking beautiful, seems to have a lot of great features up its sleeve. If anyone has had, or gets to have, a go on either (or better still, both) please could you report back with your thoughts and findings?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am big fan of Olympus but I was really  amazed with Roland R26 (Don't know release date) http://www.rolandsystemsgroup.com/products/100093 There is option (on Roloand, not on LS-100) to record from internal mics and also from microphones.

But prices of all "smart" recorders are still very high in compassion to High-End Recorders because they are about 1/2 of Tascam HD-P2 which has Time Code option very useful in movie industry. And from 1/3 to 1/4 of price Sound Devices...

I wrote some thoughts about LS-100 on my BLOG Creative Sound - http://www.creative-sound.cz/2011/portable-recorder-olympus-ls-100-new-recording-gear-in-my-studio/ maybe they help you to decide.

Comment: Thank you for the link to your blog, it was an interesting read! You said that so far you haven't read anything to suggest the LS-100 is capable of recording from internal mics and XLR/Phono inputs at the same time. Hopefully this turns out to not be true, as that's one of the features I'd like it to be able to do! I know it has the capability of having up to 8 tracks in one 'session', achieved through 'overdubbing' etc. and reviews I've read have said "multichannel capabilities", so fingers crossed it can record 4 channels at once, like the Roland, and other the far cheaper Zoom H4N!!

Comment: Thank you for response. I corrected the answer and I will correct my blog post. Roland R26 is able to record "multiple" source but LS-100 only something like "overdub" (prof by Olympus via twitter channel)

Answer (score 1):

I bought the Tascam DR-100 MK11 a couple of months after it was released and it is such a good piece of kit!  I upgraded it from the Zoom H4 (the older one) and the main benefit I have found is that it is much more user friendly, intuitive and quicker to navigate the menus. I also feel like the pre amps are easier to adjust to a suitable level with its quick gain settings and fine tuning knobs on the side. Apparently the pre amps have more gain and are much better than the older DR100.  Build quality is very good  which is the premium I feel it has over the H4n - also the wireless remote that is included (which can be also used wired). Mics are a league ahead also I feel. I would recommend a tripod stand for it to cut out handling noise - I got a small one of eBay for £1.50.

Comment: Never thought of looking on eBay for a small stand, thanks for the tip!


Answer (score 0):

I use an Olympus recorder, and it'a an old model but it really produces great quality sounds. so I am guessing this one is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the Tascam DR-100 MkII in the end and it's brilliant! The inbuilt mics are surprisingly good, the SNR is impressive. Battery-life of the rechargeable battery seems pretty decent, I haven't tested it out fully yet or tried it with phantom power on, but so far so good. The build quality is superb; sturdy metal casing, the buttons and wheel feel  nice. It even comes with a wireless remote! I would definitely recommend!